# How to save nth history on reload page using JavaScript in PrimeFaces?

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, primefaces

In UI we have 2 buttons one is update and one is cancel. First when user tries to update some records, it should get updated in cache, which is happening 1 time, but when user tried the same for n times, it is not reloading the new updated records. It used to go back to the main page.

```html
<p:commandButton id="cancelEditBtnD"
                 action="#{beanclass.cancelShipment}"
                 value="cancel"
                 update=":ShipmentForm:editForm,:UpdateUserDataForm:UpdateData"  
                 onclick="history.back()"
                 oncomplete="PF('checkWidgetVar').hide();"
                 process="@this">
```

Using above code used to go back to only one previous and returns to main page.

Also tried to implement using still now able to go to much older records like if user updates to more than 10/100/nth times at that time it is not working. It refreshed to first old record only not to the user updated record.
`history.go(-2)`
`history.go(-1)`
`history.go(0)`

Even tried using `window.location.reload()`/`location.reload()` still no success.

Comment: Why are you using the `java` tag for this question?

Comment: implementing java with primefaces so that is why I am using java